# I want to apply different shapes for each group in proc sgplot

Tags: sas

This is the code I wrote

```
proc sgplot data=via_in04;

xaxis label=" ";
yaxis label=" ";

styleattrs
dataconstrastcolors=(grlg black red blue skyblue orange green);

series x=rq_pt y=count_time / datalabel
group=newgroup lineattrs=(thickness=3);

run;
```

Here, I want to show only the graph drawn by a specific variable in the newgroup as a dotted line. Is there a way?

lineattrs is applied to all group variables collectively, so it is not possible to change only a specific variable.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `SERIES` option `GROUPLP` which allows you to specify a variable that contains the value of the line pattern to be used in the plot.  This requires you to have an extra variable in the data set being plotted.

Example:

```
ods listing close;
ods html file='plot.html';

data have;
  do group = 1 to 5;

    if group=5 
      then grouplinepattern = 20 ;  /* dashed */
      else grouplinepattern =  1 ;  /* solid */

    do x = 1 to 20;
      y = sin (x/8+group);
      output;
    end;
  end;
run;

proc sgplot data=have;

xaxis label=" ";
yaxis label=" ";

styleattrs
  datacontrastcolors=(grlg black red blue skyblue orange green)

;

series x=X y=Y
  / datalabel
    group=GROUP
    lineattrs=(thickness=3 )
    groupLP = grouplinepattern
  ;
run;

ods html close;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks to your thoughtful reply, the problem has been solved. thank you!